# Unable to include <style> tag when using requirejs with vue

Tags: vue.js, requirejs

I am trying to integrate a Vue app with an existing MVC application using require-js, require-vuejs and vue-js. Everything works fine, but when ever I add a `<style scoped>` tag inside a component, it shows an error.

If I remove the `<style scoped>` tag, it works fine.

Am I missing something?

Here is the code for my cart component (parent):

```
<template>
    <div id="vue-cart">
        <div class="cart-header">
            <div id="vue-cart-back">Back</div>
            <h3><b>BOOKING SUMMARY</b></h3>
        </div>
        <cart-body></cart-body>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    define(['Vue','vue!./cartBody/container'],function(Vue,cartBody){
        return {
            template:template,
            components: {
                'cart-body':cartBody
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

This is the code for my child component:

```
<template>
    <div class="cart-body">
        <h1>Cart body</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>


<script>
    define(['Vue'],function(Vue){
        return {
            template:template
        }
    })
</script>
```

I am rendering the component using:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'Vue': 'lib/vue',
        'vue': 'lib/require-vuejs',
        'vuex': 'lib/vuex',
        'es6-promises': 'lib/es6-promise.auto'
    },
    shim: {
        "Vue": {"exports": "Vue"},
    }
});

define(['Vue', 'vue','vuex','es6-promises'],
    function (Vue, vue, vuex) {
        Vue.use(vuex);
        require(['vue!./app/views/vue/cart','./app/views/vue/store/store'], function (app,store) {
            new Vue({
                el:'#vue-app',
                store: store,
                render: function(h){ return h(app) }
            })
        });
    }
);
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
vue-starter.js:16 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(Vue){
        return {
            template:template
        }
    }
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
    at makeError (require.js:165)
    at intakeDefines (require.js:1255)
    at require.js:1445
makeError @ require.js:165
intakeDefines @ require.js:1255
(anonymous) @ require.js:1445
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
load @ require-vuejs.js:286
(anonymous) @ require.js:1096
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
on @ require.js:512
callPlugin @ require.js:957
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
(anonymous) @ require.js:1090
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require-vuejs.js:299
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ require-vuejs.js:293
execCb @ require.js:1690
check @ require.js:865
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
load @ require-vuejs.js:286
(anonymous) @ require.js:1096
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
on @ require.js:512
callPlugin @ require.js:957
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
(anonymous) @ require.js:1090
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require-vuejs.js:299
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ require-vuejs.js:293
execCb @ require.js:1690
check @ require.js:865
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
load @ require-vuejs.js:286
(anonymous) @ require.js:1096
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
on @ require.js:512
callPlugin @ require.js:957
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
(anonymous) @ require.js:1090
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require-vuejs.js:299
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ require-vuejs.js:293
execCb @ require.js:1690
check @ require.js:865
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
load @ require-vuejs.js:286
(anonymous) @ require.js:1096
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
on @ require.js:512
callPlugin @ require.js:957
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
requirejs @ require.js:1791
(anonymous) @ vue-starter.js:16
execCb @ require.js:1690
check @ require.js:865
(anonymous) @ require.js:1140
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1204
completeLoad @ require.js:1583
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1711
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1939
load @ require.js:1679
load @ require.js:829
(anonymous) @ require.js:815
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
execCb @ require.js:1690
check @ require.js:865
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
fetch @ require.js:814
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1204
completeLoad @ require.js:1583
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1711
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1939
load @ require.js:1679
load @ require.js:829
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
requirejs @ require.js:1791
(anonymous) @ spaView.js:424
dispatch @ jquery.js:5095
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4766
trigger @ jquery.js:5007
jQuery.event.trigger @ jquery.migrate.js:493
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:5691
each @ jquery.js:657
each @ jquery.js:266
trigger @ jquery.js:5690
fire @ event.js:20
spaPackageSelected @ spaController.js:875
performAction @ ControllerClass.js:51
dispatchAction @ dispatcher.js:162
(anonymous) @ dispatcher.js:125
fire @ jquery.js:3048
fireWith @ jquery.js:3160
deferred.<computed> @ jquery.js:3249
(anonymous) @ dispatcher.js:138
execCb @ require.js:1690
check @ require.js:865
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
requirejs @ require.js:1791
moduleLoader @ dispatcher.js:132
dispatch @ dispatcher.js:108
hashChangeHandler @ dispatcher.js:62
dispatch @ jquery.js:5095
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4766
trigger @ jquery.js:5007
jQuery.event.trigger @ jquery.migrate.js:493
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:5691
each @ jquery.js:657
each @ jquery.js:266
trigger @ jquery.js:5690
finishInit @ initController.js:256
(anonymous) @ initController.js:156
fire @ jquery.js:3048
add @ jquery.js:3094
(anonymous) @ initController.js:147
fire @ jquery.js:3048
fireWith @ jquery.js:3160
deferred.<computed> @ jquery.js:3249
(anonymous) @ initController.js:393
fire @ jquery.js:3048
fireWith @ jquery.js:3160
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:3287
fire @ jquery.js:3048
fireWith @ jquery.js:3160
deferred.<computed> @ jquery.js:3249
(anonymous) @ initController.js:383
fire @ jquery.js:3048
fireWith @ jquery.js:3160
deferred.<computed> @ jquery.js:3249
fire @ jquery.js:3048
fireWith @ jquery.js:3160
deferred.<computed> @ jquery.js:3249
(anonymous) @ ModelClass.js:363
fire @ jquery.js:3048
fireWith @ jquery.js:3160
deferred.<computed> @ jquery.js:3249
(anonymous) @ rsweblib.js:329
getResponse @ rsweblib.js:70
fire @ jquery.js:3048
fireWith @ jquery.js:3160
done @ jquery.js:8235
callback @ jquery.js:8778
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery.js:8706
ajax @ jquery.js:8136
SendRequest @ rsweblib.js:73
rsSOAP @ rsweblib.js:313
getData @ ModelClass.js:327
(anonymous) @ initController.js:278
each @ jquery.js:657
initGuestItinerary @ initController.js:270
(anonymous) @ initController.js:121
fire @ jquery.js:3048
fireWith @ jquery.js:3160
deferred.<computed> @ jquery.js:3249
(anonymous) @ systemModel.js:732
fire @ jquery.js:3048
fireWith @ jquery.js:3160
deferred.<computed> @ jquery.js:3249
(anonymous) @ rsweblib.js:329
getResponse @ rsweblib.js:70
fire @ jquery.js:3048
fireWith @ jquery.js:3160
done @ jquery.js:8235
callback @ jquery.js:8778
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery.js:8706
ajax @ jquery.js:8136
SendRequest @ rsweblib.js:73
rsSOAP @ rsweblib.js:313
fetchSystemState @ systemModel.js:722
init @ initController.js:110
(anonymous) @ dispatcher.js:135
execCb @ require.js:1690
check @ require.js:865
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
requirejs @ require.js:1791
moduleLoader @ dispatcher.js:132
(anonymous) @ dispatcher.js:402
execCb @ require.js:1690
check @ require.js:865
(anonymous) @ require.js:1140
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
(anonymous) @ require.js:1140
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:983
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1015
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
finishLoad @ text.js:152
(anonymous) @ text.js:188
xhr.onreadystatechange @ text.js:300
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
text.get @ text.js:308
load @ text.js:187
(anonymous) @ require.js:1096
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
on @ require.js:512
callPlugin @ require.js:957
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
(anonymous) @ require.js:1000
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1204
completeLoad @ require.js:1583
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1711
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1939
load @ require.js:1679
load @ require.js:829
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
callPlugin @ require.js:1099
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1204
completeLoad @ require.js:1583
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1711
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1939
load @ require.js:1679
load @ require.js:829
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
requirejs @ require.js:1791
init @ dispatcher.js:365
RSWebJS.init @ app.js:110
(anonymous) @ rsweb.js:110
execCb @ require.js:1690
check @ require.js:865
(anonymous) @ require.js:1140
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
(anonymous) @ require.js:1140
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
(anonymous) @ require.js:1140
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
(anonymous) @ require.js:1140
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
(anonymous) @ require.js:1140
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:983
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1204
completeLoad @ require.js:1583
(anonymous) @ require.js:1086
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ hbs.js:612
execCb @ require.js:1690
check @ require.js:865
(anonymous) @ require.js:1140
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1204
completeLoad @ require.js:1583
(anonymous) @ require.js:1086
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ hbs.js:612
execCb @ require.js:1690
check @ require.js:865
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
(anonymous) @ hbs.js:611
xhr.onreadystatechange @ hbs.js:144
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
fetchText @ hbs.js:147
fetchAndRegister @ hbs.js:427
load @ hbs.js:650
(anonymous) @ require.js:1096
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
on @ require.js:512
callPlugin @ require.js:957
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
(anonymous) @ require.js:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1809
localRequire @ require.js:1442
(anonymous) @ hbs.js:611
xhr.onreadystatechange @ hbs.js:144
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
fetchText @ hbs.js:147
fetchAndRegister @ hbs.js:427
load @ hbs.js:650
(anonymous) @ require.js:1096
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
on @ require.js:512
callPlugin @ require.js:957
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
(anonymous) @ require.js:1000
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
(anonymous) @ require.js:1140
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
(anonymous) @ require.js:1190
each @ require.js:56
emit @ require.js:1189
check @ require.js:940
enable @ require.js:1177
init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1204
completeLoad @ require.js:1583
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1711
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1939
load @ require.js:1679
load @ require.js:829
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1204
completeLoad @ require.js:1583
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1711
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1939
load @ require.js:1679
load @ require.js:829
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
callPlugin @ require.js:1099
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1204
completeLoad @ require.js:1583
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1711
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1939
load @ require.js:1679
load @ require.js:829
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1204
completeLoad @ require.js:1583
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1711
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1939
load @ require.js:1679
load @ require.js:829
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1204
completeLoad @ require.js:1583
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1711
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1939
load @ require.js:1679
load @ require.js:829
fetch @ require.js:819
check @ require.js:851
enable @ require.js:1177
enable @ require.js:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js:131
each @ require.js:56
enable @ require.js:1114
init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1204
intakeDefines @ require.js:1260
localRequire @ require.js:1439
requirejs @ require.js:1791
(anonymous) @ rsweb.js:109
Show 544 more frames
vue-starter.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: fromText eval for vue!app/views/vue/components/cartComponent/cartBody/container failed: TypeError: define(...) is not a function
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#fromtexteval
 Url: js/app/views/vue/components/cartComponent/cartBody/container.vue
    at require-vuejs.js:304
```

Comment: Are you using webpack?  If so, have you registered the vue-loader? https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html

Comment: @StevenSpungin I am not using webpack. I am trying to build this entire thing using just the cdn for require-js, require-vuejs and vue-js. Nothing else.

Comment: Have you tried putting the <style> tag after the <script> tag? Does it work without the scoped attribute?

Comment: @StevenSpungin I have tried putting the <style> tag after <script> with and without  scoped attribute, it doesn't work. It breaks if I put the <style> tag anywhere in the file.

Comment: I updated your question, and provided a possible solution, based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a named define.  `define('cart', [...],  function(){ ... }`

```html
<script>
    define('cart', ['Vue','vue!./cartBody/container'],function(Vue,cartBody){
        return {
            template:template,
            components: {
                'cart-body':cartBody
            }
        };
    })
</script>

// and

<script>
    define('cartBody', ['Vue'],function(Vue){
        return {
            template:template
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried this and it is showing me an error in my container.vue:
define(...) is not a function
Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(Vue,vuex){
        return Vue.component('cartBody',{
            template:template,})})

Comment: Have your tried to use named defines?  This seems to be a require-js issue, not a vue issue.